# Tesseract OCR Multiple Fonts

Tags: fonts, ocr, tesseract, lstm

If we assume that we have set of fonts files, and all of there fonts files are for the same font, but each one of them is for a different style, for example if we have font "test" there will be file for test regular, and file for test bold and file for test italic, but all of these files or styles have the same font name which is "test", if I installed them all on the machine, and created single LSTM file for the font test, will the tesseract create the LSTM file for all styles or just one of these styles.

Keep in mind I cant train for every style since all styles have the same name "test" and all styles are already installed on the machine

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/AFWrhz6Dqt0), its a description of how to know what fonts do you have, on Linux OS